# Opengl ES 2.0: Model Matrix vs Per Vertex Calculation

Tags: performance, opengl-es, model, shader, bytebuffer

I may be asking a silly question but i'm a bit curious about opengl es 2.0 perfomance.

Let's say I have an drawing object that contains a Vertex Array "VA", A Buffer Array "BA", and/or a Model Matrix "MM", and I want to do at least one Translation and one Rotation per frame. So, what is the best alternative?

1. Do the operations (Rot and Trans) on VA and pass to BA.
2. Do the operations (Ror and Trans) directly on BA.
3. Do the operations on MM and pass it to Opengl Vertex Shader.

My conecern is about perfomance, the processing/memory ratio. I think that the 3rd option may be the best because of the GPU, but also the most expensive on terms of memory because every object would have to have a MM, right?

Another Solution that I thought was to pass the translation and rotation parameters to the shaders and assemble the MM on the Shader.

How this is best done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is far from a silly question but unfortunately it all depends on the case. Generally even using the vertex buffers on the GPU might not be the best idea if the vertex data is constantly changing but I guess this is not the case you are having.

So the two main differences in what you are thinking would be:

1. Modify each of the vertex in the CPU and then send the vertex data to the GPU.
2. Leaving the data on the GPU as it is and change them in the vertex shader by using a matrix.

So the first option is actually good if the vertex data are changing beyond what you can present with a matrix or any other type of analytically presented vertex transformation. For instance if you kept generating random positions on the CPU. In such cases there is actually little sense in even using a vertex buffer since you will need to keep streaming the vertex data every fame anyway.

The second one is great in cases where the base vertex data are relatively static (not changing too much on every frame). You push the vertex data to the GPU once (or once every now and then) and then use the vertex shader to transform the vertex data for you. The vertex shader on the GPU is very affective in doing so and will be much faster then applying the same algorithm on the CPU.

So about your questions:
The third option would most likely be the best if you have significant amount of vertex data but I wouldn't say it is expensive on terms of memory as a matrix consists of 16 floats which should be relatively small since 6 3d vertex positions would take more memory then that so you should not worry about that at all. If anything you should worry about how much data you stream to the GPU which again is the least with this option.

To pass a translation and rotation to the vertex shader and than compose the matrix for every vertex is probably not the best idea. What happens here is you gain a little in traffic to the GPU sending 4+3 floats instead of 16 floats but simply to begin with you send it in two chunks which can produce an overhead. Next to that you consume rather more memory then less since you need to create the matrix in the shader anyway. And if you do that you will be computing a new matrix for every vertex shader which means for each and every vertex.

Now about these matrices and the memory it is hard to say it will actually have any influence on the memory itself. The stack size is usually fixed or at least rounded so adding a matrix into the shader or not will most likely have no difference in any memory consumption at all.

When it comes to openGL and performance you primarily need to watch for:

- Memory consumption. This is mostly taken with textures, a 1024x1024 RGBA will take about 4MB which equals to a million floats or about 350k vertices containing a 3D position vectors so something like a matrix really has little effect.
- Data stream. This is how much data you need to pass to the GPU on every frame for processing. This should be reduced as much as possible but again sending up to a few MB should not be a problem at all.
- Overall efficiency in the shader
- Number of draw calls. If possible try to pack as much similar data as possible to reduce the draw calls.